# Find Max Value In Database Column With Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, database, max

Lets say I have the database table setup in this fashion,

```
ID | Name  | Area | Timestamp
---+-------+------+------------
1  | Hill  | 1    | 1293243080
2  | Sam   | 1    | 1293243084
3  | Joe   | 2    | 1293243087
4  | Bob   | 2    | 1293243089
5  | Matt  | 3    | 1293243091
6  | Billy | 3    | 1293243095
```

Then I wish to return the Name of the person with the largest Timestamp and with a certain Area number.

However, when I try to return for example the Name Bob I only get Billy because he has the largest Timestamp of everyone.

How can I get the php to select not only the person with the max Timestamp, but the person with a certain Area number also?

This is my code so far -

(I am looping it because I am displaying the name of the person with the largest Timestamp in each Area)

```
for ($t = 1; $t <= 3; $t++){
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE Area='$t' AND Timestamp=(select max(Timestamp) from forum_posts)");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       $post_name[$t]=$row['Name'];
   }
}

print_r ($post_name);
```

What do you guys suggest I do?

Comment: this is happening because you are always trying to get the highest timestamp irrespective of the area. I posted a modified query which will get the highest timestamp for each area and return the user with that timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE Area='$t' AND Timestamp=(select max(Timestamp) from forum_posts where Area='$t')");
```

a better option would be.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE Area='$t' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Just was checking this one more time before I left but that second option does not work, just letting you know. Ruined the sexy answer lol.

Answer (score 3):

use this

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE Area='$t' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 2):

You need a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) on your query.

Comment: What do you mean by this? I have never used the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Better look it up.  Start reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I doubt group by will work, because he isnt using any sort of aggregation functions.

Comment: @tHeSiD You can use `GROUP BY` in MySQL without using aggregation functions.

Comment: Wow that actually is really useful in quite a few things I need to do, but the answer from tHeSiD is what I needed, such a simple mistake ha. Thanks everyone though.

Answer (score 1):

You need a OR Condition. The query would be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE Area='$t' OR Timestamp=(select max(Timestamp) from forum_posts)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM forum_posts (
  SELECT
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS ranking,
    name
  FROM person
  WHERE area = 1
) AS foo
WHERE ranking = 1
```